# An example of Itô integral for Brownian motion. Why that equality?

Tags: probability-theory, proof-explanation, brownian-motion, expected-value, stochastic-integrals

I quote **Øksendal (2003)**

> *Statement.* Start from a 1-dimensional Brownian motion $B_t$. Assume $B_0=0$. Then $$\displaystyle{\int_0^t}B_sdB_s=\displaystyle{\frac{1}{2}B_t^2}-\displaystyle{\frac{1}{2}t}$$
> *Proof.* Put $\phi_n(s,\omega)=\sum B_j(\omega)\cdot\chi_{[t_j, t_{j+1}]}(s)$, where $B_j=B_{t_j}$ and $\chi$ denotes the indicator function on the subset $[t_j,t_{j+1}]$. Then:
> \begin{align}\mathbb{E}\bigg[\int_0^t(\phi_n-B_s)^2ds)\bigg]&=\mathbb{E}\bigg[\sum_j\int_{t_j}^{t_{j+1}}(B_j-B_s)^2ds\bigg]\\&\color{red}{=}\sum_{j}\int_{t_j}^{t_{j+1}}(s-t_j)ds\\&=\cdots\end{align}

---

What I cannot understand is the $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ equality above. How can one pass from $$\mathbb{E}\bigg[\sum_j\int_{t_j}^{t_{j+1}}(B_j-B_s)^2ds\bigg]\tag{1}$$ to $$\sum_{j}\int_{t_j}^{t_{j+1}}(s-t_j)ds\tag{2}$$? 
 Possibly, which is the role of the outer expected value $\mathbb{E}$ (with respect to a probability measure $\mathbb{P}$, I guess) in this passage from $(1)$ to $(2)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since for $s>t$, $\mathsf{E}(B_s-B_t)^2=\mathsf{E}B_{s-t}^2=s-t$,
$$
\mathsf{E}\left[\sum_{j}\int_{t_j}^{t_{j+1}}(B_s-B_j)^2\,ds\right]=\sum_{j}\int_{t_j}^{t_{j+1}}\mathsf{E}(B_s-B_j)^2\,ds=\sum_{j}\int_{t_j}^{t_{j+1}}(s-t_j)\,ds.
$$

Comment: The first equality $\mathsf{E}\left[\sum_{j}\int_{t_j}^{t_{j+1}}(B_s-B_j)^2\,ds\right]=\sum_{j}\int_{t_j}^{t_{j+1}}\mathsf{E}(B_s-B_j)^2\,ds$ follows from linearity of expectation $\mathsf{E}$, doesn'it?

Comment: @Strictly_increasing Yes, it follows from the linearity of expectations and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli's_theorem_for_non-negative_measurable_functions) result.

Comment: OK, so the fact that Tonelli-Fubini applies means that I can see $$\mathbb{E}\int_{t_j}^{t_{j+1}}(B_j-B_s)^2ds\tag{1}$$
as something like $$\int_{t_j}^{t_{j+1}}f(s, B_s) \text{ }d(s,B_s)\tag{2}$$ for a certain function (I would not be able to define) $f(s, B_s)$? $$$$ If so, why? It's just for the sake of completeness, as to the main reasoning I perfectly got your answer

Comment: $$
\mathsf{E}\left[\int_{t_j}^{t_{j+1}}(B_s-B_j)^2\,ds\right]=\int_{\Omega}\left[\int_{t_j}^{t_{j+1}}(B_s(\omega)-B_j(\omega))^2\,ds\right]\mathsf{P}(d\omega)
$$

Comment: Yeah, but doesn't Tonelli-Fubini apply where a "joint differential" $d(s, B_s)$ can be defined? Is this our case?

Comment: The product measure here is $\mu \times \mathsf{P}$, where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$. So the "joint differential" is $d(\mu\times \mathsf{P})(s,\omega)$.

Comment: Perfect explanation! Thank you a lot

Comment: Pardon, just one very last observation: so, just for confirmation, in the reference it is meant that $$\int_{t_j}^{t_{j+1}}(B_s(\omega)-B_j(\omega))^2\,ds=\int_{t_j}^{t_{j+1}}(B_s(\omega)-B_j(\omega))^2\,d\mu(s)$$ with $\mu$ Lebeasgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$? ($f(s,\omega)$ is a stochastic process)

Comment: By the way, the equality there should be stated as
$$
\int_X\left(\int_Y f(x,y)d\nu(y)\right)d\mu(x)=\int_Y\left(\int_X f(x,y)d\mu(x)\right)d\nu(y)=\ldots
$$